# Event Proposal: Let's start doing a featured spotlight on good questions and questions that need attention on our main site

Tags: discussion, community-events

As some of you may or may not know, on the site we have a small social media (unofficial, i.e., unaffliated with Stack Exchange) community for promoting our site on [Facebook](http://fbl.me/animese) and [Google+](http://goo.gl/jcdBXF). The purpose of the site is to promote attention to our main site.

On the social sites occasionally feature good answered (#mondainai) and unanswered questions (#mondaiaru) on our site. It's like to do a community based event and extended it to all questions and answers.

I'd like to create a monthly event for users to participate where they nominate a good question or answer that deserves more recognition or a question that should get more attention (it can be one with or without an accepted answer). A featured question or answer of the month, so to speak.

Sometimes good questions/answer get buried under the torrents of other question/answer and might not get the attention (or votes) they deserve. The idea is to not only bring to these types of questions and answers that users might have missed, but to also showcase what good question and answers looks like, so we can set a good example to newer users.

The idea is to start voting a month beforehand, users can nominate a question, an answer or both. They would also be asked to add a brief blurb about they they nominated it. E.g. The accepted answer to this question is purely based or conjecture and cites no facts, I think a better answer can be given; The details of said answer to X question are out of date due to recent developments in Y media. Voting will be done is one meta. Featured question and answers will be noted and marked as they are posted. After voting concludes at the end of the month, a meta will be posted with the featured question and/or answer, and a brief explanation on why it was featured (e.g. very detailed answer, curious question, need more attention, etc).

This way question/answer the could use attention can be brought up more easily to other users who might not be aware. No action is required by the users, but they can in their own volition, vote as they wish, add a bounty to attract attention, etc.

The final format of such an event is still open for discussion.

Would anyone be interested? If so, I would like to hear your thoughts and opinions.

Comment: This is brilliant! However, I would recommend if users are able to nominate _multiple_ posts (if they desire instead of one). This would broaden the impact this event has.

Comment: @Unihedron I think they should be allowed to do this, as long as they propose one question or answer per nomination. Otherwise they can make as many or as little nomination as they would like. But ideally we would feature only one or two different types (at most) at a time, so we don't spread people's attentions too thin.

Comment: I'm also in favor of this. As we get more organized about it, we should compile a list of questions already featured. We could also involve bounties if someone steps forward to offer them. (For the unanswered ones, that is.)

Comment: This would be a great, imaginative way to make sure good questions and answers get attention amid the torrential id reqs.

Comment: so basically a "bounty" of increased publicity?

Comment: Might as well throw a bounty on those as well.