# Anime.SE Spotlight! Pick questions and answers to be noticed by Senpai!

Tags: discussion, events

As proposed in [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2394/event-proposal-lets-start-doing-a-featured-spotlight-on-good-questions-and-que), let's call out the very best question and answers on our site to be noticed by Senpai. No matter how new or no matter how old. As long as they haven't been closed or are against SE guidelines, they're fair game!

[image: Notice me, Senpai!]

Nominate question and answers that are good and noteworthy, the ones that need improvement, or have been neglected, but could use some touch up questions and answers you think this site has to offer! Give them more publicity! Show new users what good questions and answer look like and/or give life to some old questions that deserve a second chance.

You can nominate a question (answered or unanswered) or answer (accepted or not accepted) that you personally think you should be featured.

On every first weekend of the month, a good (or one the need improvement/attention) question and/or answer will be chosen and feature in meta and promoted on our [Facebook](http://fbl.me/animese) and [Google+](http://goo.gl/jcdBXF) community pages. You're free to share them on other sites/channel that you frequent, if you so please. Nominated question and answer that have been featured will be edited to include the date, month and year it was featured and a link to the meta post of when it was featured.

If you haven't voted on the featured question or answer, it's recommended you give them an upvote. If you really like an answer, why not consider giving it an upvote?

Limit your nominations to one question or answer per answer post. You may submit as many questions or answers as you'd like, but make sure that question or answer hasn't been nominated before you post. It's okay to nominate your own question and/or answer. It's all fair game! Even self answered questions.

If your question doesn't get selected, don't fret! There are more chances as there are months to come!

Try to follow this general format:

> (Type of nomination, e.g. "Question")
>
> (Title of and link to the question or answer.)
>
> (Short paragraph or two of why you chose to nominate it. Was it good or was it bad? What can we do to improve it if it was bad or neglected? Be persuasive!)

Leave a comment here or in [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-), if you have any question, concerns, complaints, suggestions, etc.

Comment: Are they supposed to be questions asked in the last month or any time?

Comment: Any time, as long as they haven't been closed/locked.

Comment: This may as well replace the "bounties-for-tags" thing (at least for some time), since that wasn't working as well as I'd hoped, and I'm a bit busy lately anyway.

Comment: anime.se redirects me to a swedish based forum

Answer (score 5):

Question (needs answer)

[Is there a meaning behind the paintings in Tsubaki Kureha's living room?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/is-there-a-meaning-behind-the-paintings-in-tsubaki-kurehas-living-room)

@Gao gave an amazing answer to [About the artworks used in the Elfen Lied opening scenes (contains nudity)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15130/about-the-artworks-used-in-the-elfen-lied-opening-scenes-contains-nudity) - I wonder if we could get another very insightful answer on the art in Yuri Kuma Arashi. The show references many other series and society and I wouldn't be surprised if there's more meaning to this than meets the eye.

Comment: I originally avoided reading that question since I haven't seen the show, but the question turned out to be really interesting, and earned an upvote from me.

Comment: In the future please only include one question or answer per answer post.

Answer (score 3):

Question (attention/more answers)

[Why do guys in anime often lack nipples?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/17167/why-do-guys-in-anime-often-lack-nipples)

I think this is a question that can probably have a good definitive answer (cultural, law based perhaps) but doesn't just yet.

I think the correct answer would probably be an interesting read as over here manipples are a-ok for most age ratings if not all. Especially when the focus is not sexual (like swimming)

As much as the 'no one wants to see guy's nipples' is humourous - I would like to see if we can find out the real answer.

Comment: even this meta post got it enough attention to get another answer :)

Answer (score 3):

### Answer (accepted): [seijitsu's answer to "Why are there so many perverted virgins in anime?"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/22209/7579)

This answer was accepted and already has more upvotes than any single post I've ever written on any SE site, but I found it to be of such exceptional quality as to deserve extra praise. It deftly explains the seemingly paradoxical culture around sex and romance in Japan, and how this culture mixes with the basic rules of effective writing to lead to various things we observe in anime.

seijitsu has a record of writing interesting posts that explain where the real Japan and the anime Japan meet and where they part; for instance, I couldn't have asked for a better answer than the one I got to my question [Why do Aya and Youko consider going to a ramen shop alone so amazing?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13828/7579), especially when I wasn't really expecting to get an answer at all. This was a recent and especially fascinating example, which I felt deserved to be noticed by Senpai.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer (accepted): [Toshinou Kyouko's answer to "Are the visualizations in the anime from the light novels?"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/22021/7579)

The crux of this answer is "No." A serviceable answer would be "No, the novels never get that descriptive; it seems to be something Shaft added." But Toshinou-san goes way beyond that, taking on the entire scene when Koyomi first enters Suruga's room, and comparing the novel's mundane description of a messy room with the over-the-top ocean of BL books in the anime version, complete with translated passages and pictures. The research goes beyond anime, as the answer even goes into just how big the room in the novel was, and by how much Shaft exaggerated its size.

So far the answer only has five upvotes. I know there are at least a few more of us who follow Monogatari that could spare an upvote for an answer that went much further than it had to.

Answer (score 3):

## Question (needs attention): [In the Tsubasa Cat arc, when did Hachikuji meet Shinobu?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/22287/7579)

This question is something I've wondered about myself. In Part 3 of Tsubasa Cat, Koyomi encounters Mayoi, who tells him, after a session of their usual "Let me see your panties!" / "Shitsurei, kamimashita" routine, that she saw Shinobu at a Mister Donuts shop.

As far as I can remember, Mayoi didn't met Shinobu until the Shinobu Time arc in Second Season, and I don't remember Koyomi ever telling Mayoi about her or even explaining his situation with being part vampire. I haven't read the relevant novel. I wrote my hypothesis about what happened (in a comment), but it would be nice if someone more knowledgeable than me could offer an answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer (accepted): mirrororoftruth's answer to [What happens in the end of Tokyo Ravens?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/what-happens-in-the-end-of-tokyo-ravens)

The answer is accepted and the is another answer also. I would not have nominate this answer but looking from the view which is 9k while posting this answer the vote are very low which is just 2 and question is 4. As looking from most of the question which have higher view have more votes in question and answer. So i felt it deserve to be notice by Senpai.